# How to cancel multi-entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, eu, business-travel, visa-cancellation

I have a Schengen visa (business class) from one of the EU countries. It is multi-entry type valid for 18 months (90 day stay), I used this visa to visit the EU last month and it will remain valid till January 2015.

My question is can I cancel this visa? Or reduce the validity of it to 6 months only instead of 18 months? And if yes do they need a reason for it? Is it easy or hard to achieve the cancellation?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: if we can know why we might be able to help you...

Comment: having this visa with me will lead my company to send me again and again to EU, while I have plan to go to study in Canada next months and cz this visa they will say ok shift your study till your visa expired since it is hard to archive that visa for another one instead of you!

Comment: An embassy or consulate-general of the country which issued you the visa is able to cancel it. I don't know if they'll ask why you want it cancelled, or if the explanation you give will suffice, but they are the ones who can do it. However, doing so will likely affect your future chances of getting a Schengen visa, and since the cancellation will be in your passport, you may also be asked additional questions or be denied entry at the borders of other countries, since cancellations are usually done when something bad has happened.

Comment: You do realize that when your company asks you to go to the EU you can just say "No"? Especially if you are planning on (presumably) quitting and going to study in Canada?

Answer (score 4):

You should contact the consulate of the country that issued your visa and ask them to cancel it. Make sure they put a "cancelled without prejudice" stamp. If they do, you shouldn't have problems getting Schengen visas in the future.

If your visa is about to expire, consulates will have no problem cancelling it. But your circumstances are different and very unusual. It's hard to tell whether the consulate will ask you for a reason (most likely they will) and agree to cancel you visa (it's likely they will cancel your visa).